# clearInterval not working with jquery .hover

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a flipping effect using timeouts and setInterval with the following code:

```
// Flip and unflip panels
function startFlip() {
    $('div#front-page-mosaic .front-box.flip').find('div').stop().rotate3Di('flip', 500, {direction: 'clockwise', sideChange: mySideChange});
    setTimeout( function() {
        $('div#front-page-mosaic .front-box.flip').find('div').stop().rotate3Di('unflip', 500, {sideChange: mySideChange});
    }, 8500);
}

// Global flipping effect hook
var flip_hook;

// Autostart flipping effect
setTimeout( function() {
    startFlip();
    flip_hook = setInterval(function(){ startFlip(); }, 17000);
}, 8000);

    // Stop the flipping effect
function stopFlip() {
    clearInterval(flip_hook);
}

// Stop fliping on mouse hover, restart on mouse leave
$('div#front-page-mosaic .front-box.flip').hover(
    function () {
        stopFlip();
    },
    function () {
        setTimeout( function() {
            startFlip();
            flip_hook = setInterval(function(){ startFlip(); }, 17000);
        }, 8000);
    }
);
```

But it does not stop the effect on mouseover. Seems it is not catching the clearInterval(). Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a setTimeout to fire 8 seconds after. So if the user enters before that last setTimeout fires than it will still run. You need to cancel that timer also.

```
var delay;
function stopFlip() {
    clearInterval(flip_hook);
    clearTimeout(delay);
}

// Stop fliping on mouse hover, restart on mouse leave
$('div#front-page-mosaic .front-box.flip').hover(
    function () {
        stopFlip();
    },
    function () {
        delay = setTimeout( function() {
            startFlip();
            flip_hook = setInterval(function(){ startFlip(); }, 17000);
        }, 8000);
    }
);
```